# PyQt5 Python3 error non-default argument follows default argument

Tags: python, pyqt5

I keep on getting this error: "non-default argument follows default argument" whatever code I run using PyQt
This is the full code of my simple program
I'm using PyCharm 2017.02 and PyQt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 simple window - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = App()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/.PyCharm2017.2/system/python_stubs/1323652623/PyQtExperiment10.02.py", line 2, in 
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
  File "C:\Users\User.PyCharm2017.2\system\python_stubs\1323652623\PyQt5\QtWidgets__init__.py", line 37
    def qDrawShadePanel(QPainter, p_int, p_int_1, p_int_2, p_int_3, QPalette, sunken=False, lineWidth=1, fill, QBrush=None, QColor=None, Qt_GlobalColor=None, QGradient=None, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown; NOTE: unreliably restored from **doc**

I could not find any solutions related to PyQt5

Comment: This has got nothing to do with pyqt - it's a pycharm bug.

Comment: Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Stop using an old, buggy version of pycharm?